# match and count frequencies of words exactly from a string in R

Tags: regex, r

So I have a block of text like this:

> "the worst most unprofessional ... I wouldn't recommend...I commend her for hardwork......"

How can I match exact word "commend",  count their frequencies?

Problem:

I'm trying to count how many times the word commend appear.

```
wrds <- gregexpr(pattern = "^commend$", string, fixed = TRUE)[[1]]
length(wrds)
```

but it returns -1

and if i try:

```
gregexpr(pattern = "commend", string, fixed = TRUE)[[1]]
```

the output is 2, counting both commend and recommend

What am i missing with gregexpr?

Comment: it returns nothing that way

Comment: If you call `commend` a word, then `\b` is a word boundary. `\bcommend\b`

Comment: based on @Symbolix, to get final count use: `length(wrds[1])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't use `fixed = TRUE`. We want a regexp, not a string.
2. Use the word boundary character `\b`. To use this in a string in R you need to escape the backslash: `"\\b"`

   `wrds <- gregexpr(pattern = "\\bcommend\\b", string)[[1]]`

Definitely don't use the extra spaces. This will fail to match "commend," and so many other possibilities. That's what the word boundary is for.